# wp_mail not sending when attachment

Tags: wp-mail

I'm searching for an hour and my problem is this :

I have the following code :

```
 //This is an absolute path
 $attachments = array( $path );
 $headers = 'From: My Name <'.$email_expediteur.'>' . "\r\n";

 if(wp_mail($email_expediteur,'Daily Report',$message_texte,$headers,$attachments))
 {
      echo 'Mail was sent to  '.$email_expediteur.'<br/>';
      unlink($path);
 }
 else
 {
      echo 'mail failed...';
 }
```

Then I recieve no mail despite Mail was sent. But when I set $headers to an empty string or empty array, the encoded attachement shows in the message and the mail starts with

```
--b1_04eea9e256980b72f460839984509e98
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

So I don't understand what's going on ...